# Shading and emission settings for a flat beam saber?

Tags: modeling, rendering, shaders, shader-nodes, emission

The beam saber style and color of glow and emission I would like to replicate here in Blender:

https://i.ibb.co/SBZVP88/SD-Gundam-G-Generation-Cross-Rays-Legend-Gundam.png

[image]

While [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5U3u4jEfLHA) is indeed a potential way of creating a lightsaber glow/emission effect, it does not work on a flat plane, only a model like a cylinder or a cube.

If the beam saber above is near flat, what shading and emission settings do I use?

When I tried to copy the video at [2:43](https://i.ibb.co/K00g3V0/kurumii.png)[image], this is what I ended up with:
[image]

Comment: maybe create the halo effect in the Compositor?